# How do I find the index of the lowest value in Python?

Tags: python

So I found the lowest value in my array using `val = np.argmin(R_abs)` in line 50, but now I'm trying to find the index of that value. I tried using `val_index = [idx for idx, minval in enumerate(R_abs) if minval == val]` in line 52, but I get an empty array. What am I doing wrong? I believe .list() only works for list. R_abs is an array.

```
R_abs = abs(R-atm_tropo)
val = np.argmin(R_abs) # (line 50)
# val_index = np.where(R_abs == val)
val_index = [idx for idx, minval in enumerate(R_abs) if minval == val] # (line 52)
```

Comment: Try `R_abs.index(min(R_abs))`

Comment: I presume you're using numpy? It might be good to call that out explicitly.

Comment: [`numpy.argmin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html) _does_ return the index of the minimum value. [`numpy.ndarray.min`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.min.html) is what returns just the min value.

Comment: `abs` (the buildin function) is only callable on a numerical object i.e. int or float, not an array or list. That said, it is possible that you've imported it explicitly from numpy (`from numpy import abs` NB: I wouldn't advice this).

As @PranavHosangadi said above `np.argmin` does return the index of the smallest value. `np.min` returns the smallest value itself.

Comment: When I use .index(),  Iget the following error: "'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'". 'val_index = [idx for idx, minval in enumerate(R_abs) if minval == val] ' doesn't give me an error, it just returns an empty vector which is very confusing to me.

Comment: That's because `argmin` **already returns the index**. `val_index` is empty because `val` is **already the index**, and the index isn't one of the values in the array.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0):

Updated for NumPy Array instead of Python List:

[This article](https://thispointer.com/find-the-index-of-a-value-in-numpy-array/) suggests that you use `np.where`:

```py
import numpy as np
# Create a numpy array from a list of numbers
arr = np.array([11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 15, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17])# Get the index of elements with value 15
result = np.where(arr == 15)
print('Tuple of arrays returned : ', result)
print("Elements with value 15 exists at following indices", result[0], sep='\n')
```

Returns

```
Tuple of arrays returned :  (array([ 4,  7, 11], dtype=int32),)
Elements with value 15 exists at following indices
[ 4  7 11]
```

Comment: To my understanding, .index() only works for list and not arrays. I should have mentioned that R_abs is an array of numbers

Comment: Python itself doesn't have arrays, if your question is specific to NumPy, you should mention that in your question.